# Not able to see, send and receive message from groups in Skype (client)

Tags: skype

Earlier I was able to see the groups in my Skype client that is installed on Linux 14.04. But from few days I was not to see any groups and also not able to receive and send the message to Skype groups.

Can any body help?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. This is happening because you have logged in https://web.skype.com/ here also. Means you have already logged in with browser.

So you have to logged out from browser skype and then logged in again in skype(client).

After that open a chat window with anyone and type the below code:

```
 /dumpmsnp
```

you will get

```
* Status: LoggedOut
```

then type:

```
/mnsp24
```

you will get output

```
Restart and be a happy MSNP24 user :)
```

After this restart the skype and login again. Please ask if any question.

**Remember to logged out from browser skype  https://web.skype.com**